# LaTeX- LaTable GUI did not show up on Mac

Tags: latex

I downloaded a LaTable Mac Version but when I clicked on the file, the GUI did not show up. I am using MacBook Pro 10.6.  I am wondering if anyone is having similar problems or knows how to fix this?
This is where I downloaded the package.

http://mac.softpedia.com/progDownload/LaTable-Download-79088.html

I also downloaded Darwin that supposedly help Mac run some Windows based program.

http://tug.org/pipermail/macostex-archives/2009-April/040025.html

http://www.kronenberg.org/darwine/

Comment: Are there any error messages printed to the terminal you used to start the program?

Comment: No, nothing that I am aware of.